# Launching my app causes iPod music to stop

Tags: iphone, ios4, multitasking

I'm compiling using iOS4. When I launch my application that uses UIImagePickerController and iAds the iPod music halts and doesn't continue in the background? Any settings I have to add to my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you playing any music or sounds from your app? If so, it will mute the iPod.

Comment: No I'm not playing any music from the app. I run iPod music than launch my app that just present UIImagePickerController object in a modal view.
Thanks